# How can I read text on the screen presented as an image using sikulix IDE?

Tags: python, java, tesseract, jython, sikuli-ide

I'm using sikulix IDE version 2.0.5 in windows 10 and the usage so far is successful.

I want to read a specific single line text on the screen using sikulix IDE. I can't copy the text to the clipboard because it on an image.

I'm able to do this on eclipse IDE using Tesseract and tess4j in Java after I imported its jar.

With my project I'm looking to use sikulix IDE because I found it to be reliable in reading images.

My question now is how can I read the text on the screen presented as an image using sikulix IDE? Is there a method I can use within the sikuli IDE.

Can someone guide me!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text = Image.create("givenImage.png").text()`

If you want to read from only part of the image:

`text = Image.create("givenImage.png").getSub(x, y, w, h).text()`

where x and y are counting from the top left corner of the image as (0, 0).

Example for top of image:

```
img = Image.create("givenImage.png")
text = img.getSub(0,0,img.w, 20).text()
```

RaiMan from SikuliX

Comment: Is there a way to improve the results because on  a single line text of 7 characters I'm getting only a single character from text.